# How to get data between the two dates from mongodb using mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query

My question is simple.Tried to get record from mongodb between the two dates like[ 01-06-2020 to 07-06-2020].But not working.How to do it?

Date format is dd-mm-yyyy

mongodb records:

```
[
{ 
_id:ObjectId("5edd1df67b272e2d4cf36f70"),
 date:"01-06-2020", 
 pid:1,
 pname:"Micheck" 
},
{ 
_id:ObjectId("5edd1dk67b272e2d4cf31f72"),
 date:"03-06-2020", 
 pid:2,
 pname:"Zohn" 
},
{ 
_id:ObjectId("5edd1rf67b272e2d4cf16f73"),
 date:"07-06-2020", 
 pid:3,
 pname:"Robert" 
},
{ 
_id:ObjectId("5edd1dw67b272e2d4cf76f76"),
 date:"01-05-2020", 
 pid:6,
 pname:"Josebh" 
}
]
```

data.controller.js:

```
module.exports.getReportTableData = (req, res, next) => {
    let collectionname = req.query.collection; 

    let date1 = "01-06-2020"; //dd-mm-yyyy
    let date2 = "07-06-2020"; //dd-mm-yyyy

    let tableReportdata = dbc.model(collectionname);
    tableReportdata.find({ date: date1,date2 }, function(err, docs) {
        if (err) {
            console.log(err);
            return;
        } else {
            console.log("Successful loaded data");
            res.json({ data: docs, success: true, msg: 'Data loaded.' });
        }
    });
};
```

Comment: What's your mongo version?

Comment: @AyushGupta: 4.2.7

Comment: Not that if you can change your schema so that dates are "yyyy-mm-dd", you can query like you want and sort on the strings.

Answer (score 1):

This solution Needs Mongo server version > 4.0.0

According to OPs comment he's using version 4.2.7

Mongo is currently treating your fields as a string, and not a date, so first you'll have to convert them to dates.

**I would recommend changing your field type to date while writing to the DB, or adding a new field with date type for better performance and less overhead**

To do this conversion at runtime, you'll have to use the aggregation pipeline with the, [addFields](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/addFields/) [dateFromString](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/dateFromString/) [match](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/match/) [gte](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/gte/) and [lte](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/lte/) operators.

Your code should look like:

```
let date1 = new Date("2020-06-01T00:00:00.000Z"); // date objects
let date2 = new Date("2020-06-07T00:00:00.000Z");

let tableReportdata = dbc.model(collectionname);
tableReportdata.aggregate([{
        $addFields: {
            convertedDate: {
                $dateFromString: {
                    dateString: "$date",
                    format: "%d-%m-%Y",
                    timezone: "UTC"
                }
            }
        }
    },
    {
        $match: {
            convertedDate: {
                $gte: date1,
                $lte: date2,

            }
        }
    }
], function(err, docs) {
    if (err) {
        console.log(err);
        return;
    } else {
        console.log("Successful loaded data");
        res.json({
            data: docs,
            success: true,
            msg: 'Data loaded.'
        });
    }
});
```

[Playground Link](https://mongoplayground.net/p/1ye0SyRgp2k)

Comment: Can i use like this? let date1 = new Date("01-06-2020"); // date objects
let date2 = new Date("07-06-2020");

Comment: No, that's will be treated as `MM-DD-YYYY`, atleast in chrome and V8

Comment: @PappaS plus it's better to be explicit about the time and timezones

Comment: I have stored in db date is like string.i can not change type

Comment: How to explicit?

Comment: by including "T00:00:00.000Z" part

Comment: Need to change date type in mongodb like Date?

Comment: convertedDate? this is date field?

Comment: I have linked the docs to operators I have used in the example, you should read up on those to understand what's happening here better

Comment: let date1 = new Date("2020-06-01T00:00:00.000Z");  
let date2 = new Date("2020-06-07T00:00:00.000Z"); not working

Comment: Getting today date records only