# How to get data from mongodb between including two days in mongodb using mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query

Tried to get records from mongodb between including two days but in my code only i am getting between two days.

Example:

01-06-2020 to 08-06-2020 = getting records from 02-06-2020 to 08-06-2020(01-06-2020 missing)

But i want 01-06-2020 to 08-06-2020 = need to get records from 01-06-2020 to 08-06-2020.

How to get it?

Mongodb Data:

```
{ 
_id:ObjectId("5edd1df67b272e2d4cf36f70"),
pname:"Test 1", 
category:"Choco 1",
todaydate:2020-06-01T18:30:00.000+00:00
},
{ 
_id:ObjectId("5gdd1df67b272e2d4cf36f72"),
pname:"Test 2", 
category:"Choco 3",
todaydate: 2020-06-02T18:30:00.000+00:00
},
{ 
_id:ObjectId("5kdd1df67b272e2d4cf36f74"),
pname:"Test 5", 
category:"Choco 6",
todaydate: 2020-05-01T18:30:00.000+00:00
},
{ 
_id:ObjectId("5ewd1df67b272e2d4cf36f75"),
pname:"Test 6", 
category:"Choco 8",
todaydate: 2020-06-03T18:30:00.000+00:00
},
{ 
_id:ObjectId("5sdd1df67b272e2d4cf36f76"),
pname:"Test 3", 
category:"Choco 9",
todaydate: 2020-06-04T18:30:00.000+00:00
},
{ 
_id:ObjectId("5tdd1df67b272e2d4cf36f78"),
pname:"Test 11", 
category:"Choco 10",
todaydate: 2020-06-05T18:30:00.000+00:00
}
```

data.model.js:

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose'); 
var userSchemaDate = new mongoose.Schema({ 
    pname: {
        type: String
    },  
    category: {
        type: String
    },  
    todaydate: {
        type: Date
    }   
}, {
    versionKey: false,
    collection: 'data'
}); 

module.exports = mongoose.model('Data', userSchemaDate);
```

data.controller.js:

```
module.exports.getReportTableData = (req, res, next) => {
    var collection = req.query.collection; 
    let tableReportdata = dbc.model(collection);

    let date1 = "01-06-2020"; dd/mm/yyyy
    let date2 = "07-06-2020"; dd/mm/yyyy

    tableReportdata.find({
            $and: [{
                    todaydate: {
                        $gt: date1
                    }
                },
                {
                    todaydate: {
                        $lt: date2
                    }
                }
            ]
        }, function(err, docs) {
            if (err) {
                console.log(err);
                return;
            } else {
                console.log("Successful loaded report data"); 
                res.json({ data: docs, msg: 'Report data loaded.' });
            }
        });
   }
```

Comment: Have you checked the official documentation on [query operators](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/)?

Comment: @thammada: So can i use $gte, $lte??

Comment: That's right, best way to know is to try it out :)

Comment: $gte, $lte  Not working

Comment: It's possible that you are comparing string values to date values you have to convert them to the same type first. In order to compare date strings though, you should format them as `'%Y-%m-%d'` (year/month/day, not day/month/year) as it should be alphabetically sortable according to the actual date. Please include your schema, then we can see how `todaydate` is stored

Comment: I just saw your other question, this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62249350) from [@Ayush](https://stackoverflow.com/u/6021597) pretty much covers it, it's advisable to store date as date type instead of string.

Comment: @thammada:That code is not working..

Comment: @thammada: Schema added

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/215528/discussion-between-thammada-and-pappa-s).

Answer (score 1):

[The answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62249350) on your other question should return the correct result. I'll also emphasise that it's better to store the date as date object.

Let's try another approach by using `$dateFromString` on the input values as well.

```
tableReportdata.find({
  $expr: {
    $and: [
      {
        $gte: [
          {
            $dateFromString: {
              dateString: "$todaydate",
              format: "%d-%m-%Y",
              timezone: "UTC"
            }
          },
          {
            $dateFromString: {
              dateString: "01-06-2020",
              format: "%d-%m-%Y",
              timezone: "UTC"
            }
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        $lte: [
          {
            $dateFromString: {
              dateString: "$todaydate",
              format: "%d-%m-%Y",
              timezone: "UTC"
            }
          },
          {
            $dateFromString: {
              dateString: "07-06-2020",
              format: "%d-%m-%Y",
              timezone: "UTC"
            }
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
}, function(err, docs) {
  if (err) {
    console.log(err);
    return;
  } else {
    console.log("Successful loaded report data"); 
    res.json({ data: docs, msg: 'Report data loaded.' });
  }
});
```

Shorter version with a helper function

```
const dateUTCexpr = (dateString) => ({
  $dateFromString: {
    dateString,
    format: "%d-%m-%Y",
    timezone: "UTC"
  }
})

tableReportdata.find({
  $expr: {
    $and: [
      {
        $gte: [dateUTCexpr("$todaydate"), dateUTCexpr("01-06-2020")]
      },
      {
        $lte: [dateUTCexpr("$todaydate"), dateUTCexpr("07-06-2020")]
      }
    ]
  }
}, function(err, docs) {
  if (err) {
    console.log(err);
    return;
  } else {
    console.log("Successful loaded report data"); 
    res.json({ data: docs, msg: 'Report data loaded.' });
  }
});
```

If you have `todaydate` defined as `String` in your schema, also make sure that it's properly converted in your database, you can use the following code

```
const dateUTCexpr = (dateString) => ({
  $dateFromString: {
    dateString,
    format: "%d-%m-%Y",
    timezone: "UTC"
  }
})

tableReportdata.find({
  todaydate: {
    $gte: dateUTCexpr("01-06-2020"),
    $lte: dateUTCexpr("07-06-2020")
  }
}, function(err, docs) {
  if (err) {
    console.log(err);
    return;
  } else {
    console.log("Successful loaded report data"); 
    res.json({ data: docs, msg: 'Report data loaded.' });
  }
});
```

Comment: Getting all records..no use $gte and $lte

Comment: I put incorrect variable, should be `$todaydate` not `$date`, fixed now

Comment: Ya..I have changed..but not working..Getting all records

Comment: I think somthing is happening in dateUTCexpr

Comment: You have any solution?

Comment: This is correct?   const dateUTCexpr = (dateStrings) => ({
            $dateFromString: {
                dateString: dateStrings,
                format: "%d-%m-%Y",
                timezone: "UTC"
            }
        });

Comment: Can you check this? dateUTCexpr

Comment: It’s just a short version of the solution above, if the above doesn’t work the one with dateUTCexpr won’t either. I suspect there might be something with your data, could you copy paste your data?

Comment: Data Added..Please check

Comment: Please help..I have spent more time to find solution

Comment: Any timezone issue?   bcoz i am from india

Comment: Are you sure those are your actual documents? the `_id`s `5g...`, `5k...` are not valid hexadecimal digits. I have tried in the [playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/C_pJFxRR42M) with valid `_id`s and it does work

Comment: I have changed my todaydate type Date..So what i want to do? Where i want to change?

Comment: Hi..Have you seen my new question

Comment: Yes, I have. It's probably because of timezone. Unfortunately I'm can not find time to look into it right now.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/215564/discussion-between-thammada-and-pappa-s).